# Parsing dictionary-like Apple calendar data with PyiCloud

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using [PyiCloud](https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud) to retrieve calendar data from my iPhone. It returns something that is like a dictionary. I have tried to use ast.literal_eval to convert it to a dictionary (getting a malformed string error), and I have also tried to parse it as a string (gives error

```
'startDate': from_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

). I am a newbie with Python so I cannot figure out how to parse this to pull info like dates and event titles. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the data returned for 3 different events this month:

```
[{u'startDate': [20161208, 2016, 12, 8, 14, 0, 840], u'birthdayLastName':
None, u'endDate': [20161208, 2016, 12, 8, 15, 0, 540], u'pGuid': u'work',
u'recurrenceMaster': False, u'extendedDetailsAreIncluded': False,
u'duration': 60, u'birthdayCompanyName': None, 
u'guid': u'B5AAABCF-D15D-44C8-A3BB-6E6144F19600', u'recurrence': None,
u'tz': u'America/New_York', u'title': u'myeventname', u'localEndDate':
[20161208, 2016, 12, 8, 15, 0, 540], u'recurrenceException': False,
u'birthdayShowAsCompany': None, 
u'etag': u'C=94@U=d8521207-80a0-4660-aaf1-b9260d762128', u'location': None,
u'birthdayIsYearlessBday': None, u'birthdayFirstName': None, 
u'shouldShowJunkUIWhenAppropriate': True, u'readOnly': False, 
u'birthdayBirthDate': None, u'icon': 0, u'allDay': False, 
u'hasAttachments': False, u'localStartDate': [20161208, 2016, 12, 8, 14, 0, 840], 
u'birthdayNickname': None, u'eventStatus': None, u'alarms': []},
{u'startDate': [20161220, 2016, 12, 20, 14, 0, 840], u'birthdayLastName':
None, u'endDate': [20161220, 2016, 12, 20, 15, 0, 540], u'pGuid': u'work',
u'recurrenceMaster': False, u'extendedDetailsAreIncluded': False, 
u'duration': 60, u'birthdayCompanyName': None, 
u'guid': u'3E2491FC-AD39-4E2C-AFB4-55439FACB62E', u'recurrence': None, 
u'tz': u'America/New_York', u'title': u'myeventname', u'localEndDate': 
[20161220, 2016, 12, 20, 15, 0, 540], u'recurrenceException': False, 
u'birthdayShowAsCompany': None, u'etag': u'C=98@U=d8521207-80a0-4660-
aaf1-b9260d762128', u'location': None, u'birthdayIsYearlessBday': None, 
u'birthdayFirstName': None, u'shouldShowJunkUIWhenAppropriate': True, 
u'readOnly': False, u'birthdayBirthDate': None, u'icon': 0, u'allDay': 
False, u'hasAttachments': False, u'localStartDate': [20161220, 2016, 12, 20, 
14, 0, 840], u'birthdayNickname': None, u'eventStatus': None, u'alarms': 
[]}, {u'startDate': [20161222, 2016, 12, 22, 15, 0, 900], 
u'birthdayLastName': None, u'endDate': [20161222, 2016, 12, 22, 16, 0, 480], 
u'pGuid': u'work', u'recurrenceMaster': False, 
u'extendedDetailsAreIncluded': False, u'duration': 60, 
u'birthdayCompanyName': None, u'guid': u'0D8985EF-6B3F-4C4F-
8576-014A2DF3195D', u'recurrence': None, u'tz': u'America/New_York', 
u'title': u'myeventname', u'localEndDate': [20161222, 2016, 12, 22, 16, 0, 
480], u'recurrenceException': False, u'birthdayShowAsCompany': None, 
u'etag': u'C=97@U=d8521207-80a0-4660-aaf1-b9260d762128', u'location': None, 
u'birthdayIsYearlessBday': None, u'birthdayFirstName': None, 
u'shouldShowJunkUIWhenAppropriate': True, u'readOnly': False, 
u'birthdayBirthDate': None, u'icon': 0, u'allDay': False, u'hasAttachments': 
False, u'localStartDate': [20161222, 2016, 12, 22, 15, 0, 900], 
u'birthdayNickname': None, u'eventStatus': None, u'alarms': []}]
```

Comment: I am copy-pasting this exact string into a shell and it parses it fine. Putting it in triple quotes and using `ast.literal_eval` also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, you need to iterate over the different events using something like a `for` loop.

You would set `events` equal to the payload that you've shared here, and iterate over it like this, grabbing data from each event:

```
for event in events:
    print event['title'] # will print each event's title
```